# ckeditor inline removes images

Tags: image, ckeditor, inline

I am using ckeditor 4.x with inline editing.
I am inserting images in the HTML without ckeditor image module.
As soon as I initialize the inline editing, my  are removed.

Here is the configuration I set:
config.extraAllowedContent = 'img!src,alt,title,width,height,style,old_style,ctype,img-prop,id{*}';
config.allowedContent = true;

Could someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution !

When initializing the inline editing, add: "allowedContent"
example: _active_editor = CKEDITOR.inline(elm, { allowedContent: {img:{attributes:'*',styles:'*', classes:'*'}}...);